# CRExtensionHelper.UpdateServiceOrderHeader()

Tags: acumatica

got the following error after upgrading Acumatica from 2020r2 to 2022r2

[image]

After my research found out UpdateServiceOrderHeader() was removed from CRExtensionHelper.cs
now its  SM_CRCaseMaint.cs and SM_SOOrderEntry.cs.

I implemented the following changes but got the following error;

[image]

full code:

```
    public PXAction<CRCase> CreateServiceOrders;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Service Orders", Visible = true, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual void createServiceOrders()
    {
        CRCase crCaseRow = Base.Case.Current;
        FSxCRCase fsxCRCaseRow = Base.Case.Cache.GetExtension<FSxCRCase>(crCaseRow);
        if (crCaseRow.CustomerID == null && crCaseRow.ContactID == null)
        {
            throw new PXException("You can not create proceed." + Environment.NewLine + "The Business Account and Contact are NULL.");
        }
        if (crCaseRow.CustomerID == null)
        {
            throw new PXException("You can not create proceed." + Environment.NewLine + "The Business Account is NULL.");
        }
        if (crCaseRow.ContactID == null)
        {
            throw new PXException("You can not create proceed." + Environment.NewLine + "The ContactID is NULL.");
        }
        if (CreateServiceOrderFilter.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            fsxCRCaseRow.SDEnabled = true;
            fsxCRCaseRow.BranchLocationID = CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.BranchLocationID;
            fsxCRCaseRow.SrvOrdType = CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.SrvOrdType;
            fsxCRCaseRow.AssignedEmpID = CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.AssignedEmpID;
            fsxCRCaseRow.ProblemID = CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.ProblemID;

            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
            {
                CreateServiceOrderDocument(Base, crCaseRow, CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current);
            });
        }
    }
          
          
   
    private void CreateServiceOrderDocument(CRCaseMaint graphCRCaseMaint, CRCase crCaseRow, FSCreateServiceOrderOnCaseFilter fsCreateServiceOrderOnCaseFilterRow)
    {
        if (graphCRCaseMaint == null || crCaseRow == null || fsCreateServiceOrderOnCaseFilterRow == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ServiceOrderEntry graphServiceOrderEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ServiceOrderEntry>();

        FSServiceOrder newServiceOrderRow = CRExtensionHelper.InitNewServiceOrder(CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.SrvOrdType, ID.SourceType_ServiceOrder.CASE);

        graphServiceOrderEntry.ServiceOrderRecords.Current = graphServiceOrderEntry.ServiceOrderRecords.Insert(newServiceOrderRow);

      //CRExtensionHelper.UpdateServiceOrderHeader(
       //                                            graphServiceOrderEntry,
        //                                           Base.Case.Cache,
        //                                            crCaseRow,
        //                                           fsCreateServiceOrderOnCaseFilterRow,
         //                                           graphServiceOrderEntry.ServiceOrderRecords.Current,
          //                                         true);

       SM_CRCaseMaint.UpdateServiceOrderHeader(
                                                   graphServiceOrderEntry,
                                                   Base.Case.Cache,
                                                    crCaseRow,
                                                   fsCreateServiceOrderOnCaseFilterRow,
                                                    graphServiceOrderEntry.ServiceOrderRecords.Current,
                                                   true);

        //graphServiceOrderEntry.ServiceOrderRecords.Current.SourceID = crCaseRow.CaseCD;
        graphServiceOrderEntry.ServiceOrderRecords.Current.SourceRefNbr = crCaseRow.CaseCD;

        if (!Base.IsContractBasedAPI)
        {
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graphServiceOrderEntry, null);
        }
    }             
}
#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error [CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120) means that you need to instantiate the object before calling  UpdateServiceOrderHeader().  I would try searching the source code for other instances of this function being called and replicate the setup.

Comment: much thanks, appreciate your help. Urgently need to get rid of this error.
Will appreciate for the source code.

Comment: try dropping SM_CRCaseMaint.